# I get this error message during my project session in node,react and passport.js when i download mongoose and edit index.js file

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[I get this error message during my project session in node,react and passport.js when i download mongoose and edit index.js file....](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VkXHP.png)

Comment: Do you have mongodb running?

Comment: No...actually I installed mongoose before mongodb...

Comment: And I am totally confused with my error....so please help ...!

Comment: Mongoose requires that you have MongoDB installed and running.

Comment: I installed mongoDB community server...and in my computer mongo.exe file not working..?

Comment: Are you using **mongod.exe** (with a **d**)?

Comment: Yes i am used to running mongod.exe

Comment: Thank you ...Error Solved!!